# Regard sth. As sth

Tags: vocabulary

We can use (as) with regard when it is a verb. For example:

> They regarded him ***as*** the founder of the company.

But I ask if we must use (as) with regard, or it can be left out. For example:

> They regarded him the founder of the company.

Answer (score 1):

We must use "as" with "regard", so your second sentence is not grammatically correct.

The verb "consider" has about the same meaning, and has the structure you're trying to use:

> They **considered** him the founder of the company.

Answer (score 0):

This particular use of "as" means *appearing to be, or being*.

In your example, the person in question is being considered **as** something. To see/consider/think of someone *as* something can mean that they may not actually be that thing, but for whatever reason, they are treated as such, so the word is necessary. If this person *was* the founder of the company, you would just say he *is* that.

Comment: I think OP is asking whether *as* can be left out of the sentence.